# update sql based on outer join result set

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, outer-join

Not sure where to start on this one. I need to update a single record based on a queried set from an outer join and child table in Oracle. I drafted up a mock model in MS Access to help illustrate the situation, but this is an Oracle development.

Goal: update 'Parent' table based on result set of it's child records **without a procedure**. I would have just done a logical procedure, but the demand is to do pure SQL.

Table Structure:
[image]

I need to set Parent.Result to Y/N based on Child.Status.
Conditions: If any Child.Status = Null OR 'N' then Parent.Result = 'N'. In other words, the only condition for Parent.Result = 'Y' is if all Child.Status = 'Y'.

Here is a sample data set to show expected results.
[image]

I tried a few ways like counting child results = 'Y', case statements and other failures. I'm kinda stuck on how to create a sub-query to get the result.

Any help or guidance is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like the following. Note that this would only be a one-time update:

```
UPDATE parent p
   SET p.result = (
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM join j INNER JOIN child c
            ON j.child_fk = c.child_pk
         WHERE j.parent_fk = p.parent_pk
           AND ( c.status IS NULL OR c.status = 'N' ) )
    ) THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END;
```

You don't mention whether a parent's result can be `Y` if there are no children. The above assumes that it would be.

Comment: Genius, would never had thought to use 'Exists' in a case statement with joins. So much to learn!!! Thanks David